# Is there a Visual Studio keyboard shortcut for "go to variable type definition" for "auto" variables in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I often use `F12` `Edit.GoToDefinition` and `Alt+F12` `Edit.PeekDefinition` for jumping around and looking at code.  It is pretty useful for finding the type of a variable too, `Alt-F12` on a variable then scoot over and `Alt-F12` on the type and I can look at object definitions, for example.

However, if you're using the C++ `auto` keyword, you can't `Alt-F12` on it to jump to the deduced type.  If you hover over the variable like `item` below, you can see the deduced type okay in the content popup, but you can't click on anything to jump to it.  Looking at the options-keyboard-shortcuts, it seems like running `Edit.GoToTypeDefinition` `Ctrl+K, Ctrl+Shift+T` on the variable was what I'm looking for, but it doesn't seem to work even on regular variables, much less auto ones.  Anyone run into this or have a shortcut solution?

```
if ( const auto item = getFirst() ) { {
    ...
}
```

Comment: This works for me on 16.3.2. What version do you have?

Comment: It usually works fine if your code compile properly and you don't make too much changes at once such that IntelliSense database can remain essentially up-to-date.

Comment: Hmmm... I'm on VS2019 16.3.6... my code does compile fine but it is a very large project, I'll keep playing with it, thanks

Answer (score 3):

I hold `Ctrl` then click on `auto` (or any other type) and it takes me where the type is defined. Not strictly a kyboard shortcut, but it works nevertheless.